# Multiple XAxis with ZedGraph

Tags: c#, zedgraph

With ZedGraph, I can add multiple YAxis by doing the following:

```
YAxis yAxis3 = new YAxis("Distance, m");
pane.YAxisList.Add(yAxis3);
```

Is there a similar way to add an additional XAxis, that is not X2Axis?

What I want to do is have the inside XAxis reflect the month of the data.  The outside XAxis would reflect the year.  This way everything scales correctly without redundant information to the user.  Both would be tied to the same value, just one displayed as `MMM` and the other as `yyyy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer: AFAIK unfortunately **not**.

Please provide more detailed information (e.g. why do you need another x-axis) maybe there's some workaround.